# custom control in wpf, add and remove default values when control added

Tags: c#, wpf

I think i don't have the right words but then please be kind.

My purpose is to make a textbox erasing its own text after a delay, i made custom control inheriting of textbox.

I made 2 dependency properties:

1. One for override? text property because i don't want to let the possibility to bind or change text from the wpf code... But when i add in a page my code, there is automatically `Text="CustomControlName"` that appears, i would stop this automatic add, because my property has just a get accessor.

- C# part:

```
        public new static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(TextBoxExt), new
                PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)));


        //private string _TextField;

        public new string Text
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }

       // --- OnTextChanged methods that i don't use, an error perhaps ?
```

- Xaml Part

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxExt}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TextBoxExt}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            >
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

2. Second is to specify delay before to auto erase content, i would to show (how to say?) automatically add `Delay="15"` when i add my control into a page/window (like `width=""`). I tried a lot of things, but because of my lack of vocabulary i don't know well find (i use visual studio community). I tried "meta" from here to look what was the functioning.

```
    private static FrameworkPropertyMetadata meta = 
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(15,   // default = 1
           FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
               FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentMeasure
               );
       public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Delay", typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxExt), meta);

       [Description("Maximum delay before erasing"), Category("Security")]
       public int Delay
       {
           get => (int)GetValue(DelayProperty);
           set => SetValue(DelayProperty, value);
       }

       // --- On delay changed (not used for the while)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't "remove" the `Text` property from the type. It's part of the public API whether you like it or not. If you don't want your custom control to have a public `Text` setter, `TextBox` is not a good class to derive from I am afraid.
2. Set the default value of the dependency property to `15` when you register it:

   ```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Delay), typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxExt),
            new PropertyMetadata(15));
   ```

   This doesn't affect the XAML markup where your control is being used in any way. Any consumer of your control can set the `Delay` property to any `int` value they want. If they don't set the property at all, the default value is applied, i.e. `<local:local:TextBoxExt />` is equivalent to `<local:local:TextBoxExt Delay="15" />` assuming the default value of `Delay` is `15`.

When it comes to erasing the content, you could implement it using a timer. Something like this:

```
public sealed class TextBoxExt : TextBox, IDisposable
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Delay), typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxExt), 
           new PropertyMetadata(15));

    [Description("Maximum delay before erasing"), Category("Security")]
    public int Delay
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(DelayProperty);
        set => SetValue(DelayProperty, value);
    }


    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        if (cancellationTokenSource != null)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        }

        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Delay(Delay * 1000, cancellationTokenSource.Token)
            .ContinueWith(_ => SetValue(TextProperty, string.Empty), 
            CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }

    public void Dispose() => cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. I never tried to make a control like this, if you don't inherit from textbox, how you can do to have a text area ? The only way i know in wpf is to put a textbox or textblock inside the custom control, then inherit from control and make my own dependencies it's not barbaric if i do like this  ?

For the dependency i used as you said before to post but i would to have that the default values appear between <customcontrol /> in the wpf code.

Comment: @Vonkel: What is "wpf code"? `<customcontrol />` seems to be XAML and as I mentioned, the default properties are not set by default in the markup.